# Design of an appropriate class to hold a model of data

Tags: c#

```
class Child1
{
    string Sequence;
    string Specialty;
    string Taxonomy;
}

class Child2
{
    string AddressSeq;
    string DisplayProvider;
}

class AllTogether
{
    Dictionary<ProviderKey, List<Child1>>;
    Dictionary<ProviderKey, Child2>;
}
```

I am trying to write a model that keeps this kind of information:

Center of everything is `ProviderKey`, now each provider has one `AddressSeq` and one `DisplayProvider` values. But each provider can have **multiple** `Sequence`, `Specialty` and `Taxonomy` values.

These three are always together for example

```
Sequence = 1
Specialty = Eye
Taxonomy = 1021X
```

But still I am not sure if I have designed it correctly. Can you please make suggestions?
I know it is not fully compilable C# code, just as a pseudo-code of C#, I typed in NotePad!

Comment: sounds like `Child2` should have a `List<Child1>`.  Then you have one Dictionary, and a `ProviderKey` will give you all the properties you need.

Comment: Put list of List<Child1> as property to Child2, so you'll end up with one Dictionary property in AllTogether?

Comment: this is why entityframework was born http://www.asp.net/entity-framework

Comment: please write your suggestions in the answers with sample code :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
class Child1
{
   string Sequence;
   string Specialty;
   string Taxonomy;
}

class Child2
{
   string AddressSeq;
   string DisplayProvider;
   List<Child1> List;
}

class AllTogether
{
    Dictionary<ProviderKey, Child2>;
}
```

Is what I was getting at in the comment

Comment: Thank you. I can't do this in Two classes instead of Three classes, Can I ?

Comment: Im not sure how you're using your `AllTogether` class, but the other 2 are pretty distinct objects, and should really be kept that way

Answer (score 1):

Since you were using "Provider" as the subject of your sentences, why not create a Provider class to hold all your data?

```
public class Child1
{
    string Sequence;
    string Specialty;
    string Taxonomy;
}

public class Provider
{
    ProviderKey Key;
    string AddressSeq;
    string DisplayProvider;
    List<Child1> list;
}
```

Definitely rename "Child1" and "list" though, for readability and posterity.

EDIT: For nonlinear search time, you could make a dictionary linking each ProviderKey with its Provider.

```
Dictionary <ProviderKey, Provider> providers;
```

Comment: Wasn't Dictionary used for non-linear search time in original post?